Homogenization of a prime ideal is prime
I'm studying from Qing Liu's book and I'm a bit stuck in his construction of $\operatorname{Proj}(B)$.
In particular Lemma 2.3.35 says that if $I$ is a prime ideal then $I^h= \bigoplus _{d\geq 0} I\cap B_d$ where each $B_d$ are the homogeneous elements of $B$ that have degree $d$, is also a prime ideal.
In the proof he takes $a,b \in B$ such that $ab \in I^h$ and supposes that $a,b \notin I^h$ and then write the homogeneous decomposition of $a$ and $b$ and assumes that neither of the components with maximum degree is in $I^h$ and here is what I don't understand. Why can we suppose that?
From there the proof follows easily because the product of the maximum degree components is the maximum degree component of theory product and thus is contained in $I^h \subseteq I$ from which we get that one of this maximum degrees components is in $I^h$ which contradicts the before made assumption.

You can use $\operatorname{Proj} B$ to format $\operatorname{Proj} B$. I've made this improvement for you this time.

Write $a=a_0+\cdots+a_m$ and $b=b_0+\cdots+b_n$ for $a_i,b_i\in B_i$. Assume $ab\in I^h$ but $a,b\notin I^h$. I claim if $a_m\in I^h$, then $a'=a-a_m$ and $b'=b$ still satisfy $a'b'\in I^h$ and $a',b'\notin I^h$:

$a'b'=(a-a_m)b=ab-a_mb$, so by the assumption that $a_m$ and $ab$ are both in $I^h$, we have $a'b'\in I^h$.
$b'=b\notin I^h$, and if $a'\in I^h$ then as $a_m\in I^h$, we would have $a=a'+a_m\in I^h$, contrary to our assumption. Thus $a'\notin I^h$.

Repeating this process and potentially interchanging $a$ and $b$, we may assume that neither $a$ nor $b$ have their highest-degree nonzero term in $I^h$.
